# Increase size data/log file SQL with job schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Would appreciated if anyone can suggest the right query to increase data/log file size if free space 20% from the current size?

Need some SQL query that is able to add 30% from current size of the data/log if the free space is below 20%.

I have this query to identify the current size

```
SELECT a.NAME, 
       a.FILENAME, 
       [FILE_SIZE(MB)] = convert(decimal(12,2), 
       round(a.size/128.000,2)),  
       [SPACE_USED(MB)] = convert(decimal(12,2), round(fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2)),  
       [FREE_SPACE(MB)] = convert(decimal(12,2), 
       round((a.size-fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)) ,  
       [FREE_SPACE(%)] = convert(decimal(12,2), 
       (convert(decimal(12,2),round((a.size-fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)) / convert(decimal(12,2),round(a.size/128.000,2)) * 100)) 
FROM dbo.sysfiles a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add `30%` of the current size using the build-in auto-growth option.

[image]

[image]

Why you need to do the `SQL Server` job and to increase the size in advanced? Just let the engine to do the job.

If you are worried that such tasks are slow, you may one to check [Instant File Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization).

Anyway, if you still want to do this by yourself, having the current size, means you can calculated the new one. You can than use:

```
ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'mydatabase', SIZE = ...KB );
ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'mydatabase_log', SIZE = ...KB );
```